# Is it possible and if so how to build a neural network such that it doesn't backpropagate in certain regions of the NN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, backpropagation

I had an idea to improve a neural network I'm currently using, but I'm quite new to machine learning so I don't know if it's possible to implement or how difficult it is or simply if isn't worth. The idea is this. I have a sample of images and I have to classificate them between signal and background (0 or 1). The thing is that these images, which have a variable x associated, are quite correlated to this variable, meaning that two images with a similar value of x in general will be much more similar to two images with very separated values of x. So I thought that maybe it would be a good idea to kind of train this sample into minisamples, each image taking more into account the weights trained by images with a similar x. And this is how I thought to implement it (maybe this implementation isn't really viable so if you know a more viable way feel free to tell me):

For now I am using a Convolutional Neural Network for the whole sample, using Keras, and it's like this:

```
def buildCNN(input_shape):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    return model
```

My idea is to arrange the sample into for example 20 minisamples of similar x, and use this same CNN for every one of these minisamples (maybe reducing a bit the number of parameters), and then connect these different CNNs with some weights and biases. Then, when training and comparing the output with the actual value, when backpropagating I would like to only take into account for the training these external weights along with the CNN corresponding with the range of x corresponding to the image being trained, leaving the values of the parameters of the rest of the CNNs untouched. Now, I don't know if something like this exists and if so how it can be implemented to Keras. You can see in my code that it's quite simple, and don't know much about Keras, so if you have any idea how to do this I would also need specifically how it can be implemented using Keras (and if it's impossible with Keras then say if other options are possible and how).

(By the way, a bonus question, doesn't relate for anything with the main question so it's not necessary to answer, but if you know something about it it would help. The images I'm using have a shape of (40, 40), so they have low resolution. They are not the type of images that can pass through a filter augmenting its resolution, so I have no other option but to work with this resolution. The thing is that the CNN that I'm using for now works fine, but I think it could be improved if a specific architecture for low resolution images was used, but I haven't been able to find anything about it. If you know something about this please comment it too.)

**Edit:** To understand better what I'm trying to do I'll explain exactly what my type of input is and how I want to treat it. My input are 40x40x1 images (no colour). In these images actually there are only a few pixels that are not 0, which usually come in clusters. The thing is that the signal and the background images tend to form different types of clusters, which is a perfect task for the CNN. Also, the shape of these clusters depends on this mentioned variable x, meaning that if you have learned to discriminate between signal and background images at large x, this knowledge may not be of use (actually it has some use) for lower x. That's why I want to organize these samples into smaller samples such that when training a specific image, this training only affects on the weights of its CNN (i.e. the ability to discriminate better of its CNN), and only affect the other CNNs via these weights that connect them, such that the shape of this specific image doesn't distort the discrimination ability of images of the specific range of x for other CNNs.

Comment: In practical terms, how exactly would that differ of just using mini-batch gradient descent? At each step of GD you would make update for the minibatch, then the updates get "averaged".

Comment: I've just searched about mini-batch GD (as I said I'm still quite new) and from what I understood I don't see how it can be implemented in the example I said. As I understood it, this type of GD uses smaller batches to train but in the end all events in a sample end up having an impact in all the weights. What I want is that this training only affects a specific region along with the weights connecting that region with the other ones.

Comment: I'm not following what you mean from your description. Maybe you could give example?

Comment: I don't know any case similar to this idea I want to implement, so I'm going to try to explain the motivation behind this idea so that we can see if it's actually viable. As I said images with a similar value of x will in general be more similar, therefore I want these images to acquire more importance than the others, therefore dividing it into minisamples. But the images from a minisample right next to another will also be more similar than the images of the minisample at the other end, therefore I want a weight to give it some voice (more voice than this other minisample at the other end).

Comment: But these external weights would have the function of saying how much a minisample affects another one, and just that, I don't think an image should tell the CNN of another minisample how to recognize its images (actually maybe it would be best?) so the changing of values should only occur in these external weights, but not in the other CNNs.

Comment: Maybe just edit your question to give us simple plain English description of what is your data and what are you trying to achieve. I still don't get it. Moreover, it really sounds like you are trying to re-invent some wheel, I just don't get which one yet.

Comment: Just edited it. I'm sorry if I'm not being clear and I'm giving you the sense that I'm trying to present some revolutionary idea that has already been done, but I'm trying to explain myself the best that I can, and I still don't know much how to move around and communicate in this field, so I'm not quite fond of this kind of underminig of your last comment. I hope I made myself clear with the edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108584/discussion-between-mr-nobody-and-tim).